# No environment variable displayed through kubectl

Tags: linux, bash, kubernetes, environment-variables, sh

To display some environment variables in a pod on Kubernetes, I tried it in two ways.

(1) Connecting inside a pod

I connected to shell in a pod and I executed 'echo' command like below..

```
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> /bin/bash

then...

echo $KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST
```

I saw correct result as I expected.

(2) Send a command to a pod

```
kubectl exec <pod-name> -- echo $KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST
```

In this case, there is no output.

you can see the screenshot what I did.
[image]

What is the problem here?
What is difference between two situations?

Thanks you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case, '$' DOllar in the command references to your local host envrionment variables. And there is no such variable KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST on local host, the command that goes looks like below

kubectl exec  -- echo

use below instead

kubectl exec c-hub-admin-app-systest-6dc46bb776-tvb99 -- printenv | grep KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST

[image]

Comment: Do you know why act like that? I read the official documents and references, I didn't figure that out why kubectl stops read from '$'.